# How do I increase the index number of i?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I took this code sample from w3schools:
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_dom_html_callback

I want to increase the index number of `i`.
How do I do this without showing zero on both the .text and .html code blocks?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#btn1").click(function(){
             $("#test1").text(function(i, origText){
               return "Old text: " + origText + " New text: Hello world! (index: " + i + ")"; 
             });
           });
         
           $("#btn2").click(function(){
             $("#test2").html(function(i, origText){
               return "Old html: " + origText + " New html: Hello <b>world!</b> (index: " + i + ")"; 
             });
           });
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p id="test1">This is a <b>bold</b> paragraph.</p>
      <p id="test2">This is another <b>bold</b> paragraph.</p>
      <button id="btn1">Show Old/New Text</button>
      <button id="btn2">Show Old/New HTML</button>
   </body>
</html>
``
```

Comment: Use `(i+1)` in the string expressions.

Comment: Are you trying something alike : `$(document).ready(function(){
let i = 0;
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
  i--;
    $("#test1").text(function( origText){
      return "Old text: " + origText + " New text: Hello world! (index: " + i + ")"; 
    });
  });

  $("#btn2").click(function(){
    i++;
    $("#test2").html(function( origText){
      return "Old html: " + origText + " New html: Hello <b>world!</b> (index: " + i + ")";
    });
  });
});` ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following. This uses the increment operator.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("#test1").text(function(i, origText) {
      return "Old text: " + origText + " New text: Hello world! (index: " + ++i + ")";
    });
  });

  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    $("#test2").html(function(i, origText) {
      return "Old html: " + origText + " New html: Hello <b>world!</b> (index: " + ++i + ")";
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="test1">This is a <b>bold</b> paragraph.</p>
<p id="test2">This is another <b>bold</b> paragraph.</p>

<button id="btn1">Show Old/New Text</button>
<button id="btn2">Show Old/New HTML</button>
```

All indexes are generally 0-based. This increments the variable before being used.

Now if you want to capture the number of Clicks for each button, this is not the way to manage it. Consider this example.

```js
$(function() {
  var t, h;
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    t = $(this).data("clicks") || 0;
    t++;
    $("#test1").text(function(i, origText) {
      return "Old text: " + origText + " New text: Hello world! (count: " + t + ")";
    });
    $(this).data("clicks", t);
  });

  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    h = $(this).data("clicks") || 0;
    h++;
    $("#test2").html(function(i, origText) {
      return "Old html: " + origText + " New html: Hello <b>world!</b> (count: " + h + ")";
    });
    $(this).data("clicks", h);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="test1">This is a <b>bold</b> paragraph.</p>
<p id="test2">This is another <b>bold</b> paragraph.</p>

<button id="btn1">Show Old/New Text</button>
<button id="btn2">Show Old/New HTML</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return "Old text: " + origText + " New text: Hello world! (index: " + (i + 1) + ")"; 

return "Old html: " + origText + " New html: Hello <b>world!</b> (index: " + (i + 1) + ")";
```

use **`(i + 1)`** in the string.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood it correctly, but if you are looking to display the number of clicks in HTML without showing the initial text, then this is the working code for it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var para1 = 0, para2 = 0;
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
  
    para1++;
    $("#test1").text("New text for para1 : "+para1);
  });

  $("#btn2").click(function(){
  
    para2++;
    $("#test2").text("New text for para2 : "+para2);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="test1">This is a <b>bold</b> paragraph.</p>
<p id="test2">This is another <b>bold</b> paragraph.</p>

<button id="btn1">increase i in para 1</button>
<button id="btn2">increase i in para 2</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI: Use `data` instead of DRY.   `$(".btn").click(function() { $(this).text("text" + $(this).data("param")); $(this).data("param",  $(this).data("param") + 1); })` (or so)